# "No Overload Method for GetLine" Help (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have tried something like: "GetLine(fileName,line)" no luck

Code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GetLine();
        }


        string GetLine(string fileName, int line)
{

......

}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Where is your `GetLine` defined? Why do you have a call to one that has no parameters passed in?

Comment: You haven't been very clear about what you're trying to do or what problem you've got. Based on the information you posted, it looks like you have a method called GetLine that takes a string and int argument however, you're calling a method named GetLine passing no parameters. Therefore the compiler is looking for a method definition for GetLine that is defined with no parameters and it cannot find one. If you had defined GetLine with default values for the parameters, your GetLine() call would have compiled. Is this enough of an explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the GetLine declared non-static from within a static function.

Either mark the GetLine declaration as static, or create an instance of the class containing both the functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to overload the method `GetLine` it must be marked with the `virtual` indicator.

```
virtual string GetLine(string fileNmae, int line)
{
    //Code for method goes here
}
```

Update :

As Mario Vernari suggested you will need to make the method static.

If you want to call the method like this `GetLine()` then you will need to create a new overloaded method for GetLine.

```
static string GetLine()
{
   return "Some string message"; //Return a string.
}
```

Comment: He is not trying to overload the method `GetLine`, the problem is `GetLine` is not static but `Main` is. See Mario's answer

Comment: @Kieren, thats true, but he is also trying to call the GetLine method without passing in any parameters which is what's giving him the message "No Overload Method for GetLine". He will need to to do two things make the method static and either pass in no paramenters or overload the GetLine() method to accept no parameters.

Comment: @Jethro - neither of those relate in any way to adding the `virtual` keyword, which is what your answer says, which is wrong

Comment: @Kieren, I've updated my answer to show this.

Comment: It's not an overloaded method - sorry, this answer is just wrong!  Try your luck next time!

Answer (score 0):

it should be a static method if you want to call directly like that.
`private static string GetLine(string fileName, int line)`